# How are delta file backups encoded?

Tags: c#, backup

With a backup application, a good and space-efficient way to back up is to detect changes in files. Some online services such as Dropbox do this as well since Dropbox includes version history. How do backup applications detect changes in files and store them?

If you have a monumentally large file which has already been backed up, and you make a small change (such as in a Microsoft Word document), how can an application detect a change and process it? If the file has changes made often, there must be an efficient algorithm to only process changes and not the entire file. Is there an algorithm to do this in C# .NET?

**Edit:** I'm trying to figure out how to *encode* two files as the original and the changes (in a VCDIFF format or etc.) I know how to use the format and decode it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

to detect changes, you can compute the *Hash* code (such as **MD5**) for the original and the modified versions of the file. if they are identical, no changes are made.
I think DropBox has its own protocol to detect which part of this file is modified. 
you can figure out to find out your own way, for example, divide the file to fixed-size parts, store their hash codes. when the client download the file, send these information to the client. after modifying the file, recalculate the hash codes for the parts, compare them with original hash codes, upload the parts that were modified, rebuild the file from original parts and the modified parts.
[rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) is an open source tool that synchronizes files using delta encoding.

----------------------------------------------------
**EDIT:** my idea above is very simple and not efficient.
 you can a look at **[VCDIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCDIFF)** that were explained by research paper and implemented in many languages (C#).

Comment: I'm looking for a way to process changes. This system isn't efficient if a small word is added in an extremely large text file, especially if it's in the beginning. Every block in the file after the small change will be modified. I need it to work with modifications, addition of data, and removal of data.

Comment: @PhoenixLogan : you are right, my idea was very simple and not efficient. I Edited my answer.

Comment: VCDIFF works on compressed files. I recommend to read about : http://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/